# Can I distribute In-house app which is intended to be run as root privilege through iOS MDM?

Tags: ios, mdm

Can I distribute In-house app which is intended to be run as root privilege through iOS MDM?

In other words,

Can apps which are distributed under MDM Certificate executed with elevated privilege?

Comment: why do you need to run an App with root privilege ?

Comment: We need to ensure location information of students(MDM Clients). However, in-door geolocation is not so accurate, so we are trying to adjust location information with WIFI environment(near by AP BSSIDs). To collect nearby wireless AP information, Root Privilege is required.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, this is not possible unless all the devices are jail-broken. In-house apps do not have any additional privileges to other apps, other than being able to run on any device.

Comment: So, All MDM Agent apps complies with sand-box nature, is it True?